# How to set an inputfield in an xe:formtable to stretch out to the form table width?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using the formtable control from extlib like this:

```
<xe:formTable id="formTable1" fieldHelp="false" labelPosition="above">
    <xe:formRow id="formRow1" label="Name" for="inputText1">
        <xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
    </xe:formRow>
</xe:formTable>
```

And it produces the following HTML

```
<fieldset id="view:_id1:formTable1" class="lotusForm">
<table class="lotusFormTable" role="form" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="lotusFormFieldRow">
            <td colspan="3">
                <div style="padding-left: 25px" class="lotusFormLabel">
                    <label for="view:_id1:inputText1">Name</label>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-left: 25px">
                    <input type="text" id="view:_id1:inputText1" name="view:_id1:inputText1" class="xspInputFieldEditBox"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result look like this using the bootstrap theme.

[image]

The problem I have is that I want the inputfield to have a width of the form table. 
I have tried to set the formtable and inputfield width using css but it does not work.

how can I change the formtable so it set the inputfield to stretch out to the formtable width? (or how can I control the width of the inputfield)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css to your XPage

```
.lotusFormTable, .xspInputFieldEditBox {
    width: 100%
}
```

It will expand the table and the input text field to 100%.

Comment: thanks, the solution was actually  .form-table{width: 100%} for the bootstrap theme. Your solution is correct for the oneui theme

Comment: Actually, my solution is related to the rendered HTML example in your question. I tested it with a database with server default's theme.

Comment: yes, you are right , I must have tested the onui theme when I was taking the snapshot

Answer (score 1):

Did you add a CSS class or an inline CSS? I always set the CSS width via my theme so that it results in an inline CSS for each input field - not an elegant way but it works.

This is my theme content for input fields:

```
<control>
        <name>InputField.EditBox</name>
        <property>
            <name>style</name>
            <value>width:100%;padding:3px;margin:0</value>
        </property>
    </control>
    <control>
        <name>InputField.TextArea</name>
        <property>
            <name>style</name>
            <value>width:100%;padding:3px;margin:0</value>
        </property>
    </control>
    <control>
        <name>InputField.Secret</name>
        <property>
            <name>style</name>
            <value>width:100%;padding:3px;margin:0</value>
        </property>
    </control>
    <control>
        <name>InputField.DateTimePicker</name>
        <property>
            <name>style</name>
            <value>width:100%;padding:3px;margin:0</value>
        </property>
    </control>
    <control>
        <name>ComboBox</name>
        <property>
            <name>style</name>
            <value>width:100%;padding:3px;margin:0</value>
        </property>
    </control>
```

In addition I put a HTML div around each formColumn/formRow. Maybe this is the trick...

Comment: I think the problem lies with the table width not being set to 100%. so even if I set the inputfield to 100% it will not stretch to the fieldset tag.

Comment: Yes of course you have to set the formtable also to a fixed value or to 100%. Remember: 100% works only if the container above has width, too.

Comment: I do understand what i need to do but there is no way to set the table width using the formtable control atrributes. I know I can use of lot of workarounds to fix this but I was hoping for a clean solution using the control settings